# Authenticated login architecture for Express/Node app

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, express

Sorry for asking open-ended architectural advice.

What's a good design pattern for handling authenticated login sessions in a web app using connect-redis and passport.js for session management and authentication?

Should the login service provide a temporary token?

Should that token be persisted to the session store or passed through http GET?

How should I provide a common authentication architecture for both the client app and the API services it is built on that themselves could power other apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/) framework. It has a beautiful session module, with persistent session cookie. The sessions can either be saved into redis,mongodb etc.

Comment: I'm really asking about the *authenticated* session piece. Connect-redis *is* the Express session module persistence layer.